# phpBB issue cant follow the error

Tags: sql, phpbb, phpbb3

I am building a bridge into an app and phpBB, it was working great but today I got this.

```
General Error
SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

[0]

An SQL error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact the Board Administrator if this problem persists.
```

I looked into the error_log of phpBB but there was nothing there, the last message was from about a month ago..

I also went into the error log of the server, but there was nothing there related to this..

How in the name of phpBB do you know which line is producing this error? How can I debug this phpBB code?

Comment: did you check the host of your database? maybe your db is down right now

Comment: thanks i think it was that actually, but there should be a way to check when there is other problem , but as i google i think when there is an error is displayed in that page actually.. so i guess the prob is when connecting to db